# Show uniform convergent in $[-r,r]$

Tags: convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I have to find the radius of convergence for  $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)x^n$, $x\in \mathbb R$.

I think it is: $r^{-1}$=$\lim_{n\to \infty}$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$=1   $=>$ $r$=1.
Then I have to show that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)x^n$ is uniform converget in the interval $[-r,r]$. I think I can use Weierstrass Majorant test. But I can't see what I can use as upper bound? Can anyone help?

Comment: It is the third question today about this series! Maybe next time it would be a great idea to go for an all-in-one question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Radius of convergence and uniformly convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3696751/radius-of-convergence-and-uniformly-convergence)

Comment: You can accept answers to show that you appreciate the work of the people.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: show that if $0 \leq x \leq 1$, $0 \leq x-\sin{x} \leq x^3/6$.