# Radius of convergence and uniformly convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, uniform-convergence

I think the radius of convergence for  $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)x^n$, $x\in \mathbb R$ is:

$r^{-1}$=$\lim_{n\to \infty}$$|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$|=1   so we get that $r$=1.

But how can I show it formally?

After that, I have to show that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)x^n$ is uniformly convergent in the interval $[-r,r]$. Can I maybe use Weierstrass majoranttest? What can I use as majorant serie?

Comment: Just use $1/n-\sin(1/n)\sim 1/6n^3$ as others have explained in response to your many questions on the subject.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}((1/n)-\sin(1/n))$..?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315156/convergence-of-the-series-sum-n-1-infty1-n-sin1-n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac1n-\sin\left(\frac1n\right)}{\frac1{n^3}}=\frac16$$and since the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n^3}$ is $1$, it follows from the comparaison test that the radius of convergence of your series is $1$ too.

By the same argument, together with the help of the Weierstrass $M$ test, it follows that the series converges uniformly on $\overline{D(0,1)}$. In fact, since the sequence$$\left(\frac{\frac1n-\sin\left(\frac1n\right)}{\frac1{n^3}}\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$$converges, it is bounded. Take $M\in(0,\infty)$ such that$$(\forall n\in\Bbb N):\left|\frac{\frac1n-\sin\left(\frac1n\right)}{\frac1{n^3}}\right|<M.$$Then you have, if $|z|\leqslant1$,$$\left|\left(\frac1n-\sin\left(\frac1n\right)\right)z^n\right|\leqslant\frac M{n^3}|z^n|\leqslant\frac M{n^3}$$and the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac M{n^3}$ converges.

Comment: Thank you it makes a bit sence. Can you maybe write a bit more about the argument for uniformly convergent by Weierstrass  test?

Comment: Done. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thank you. Now it makes sense

Comment: is the proof to the first limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac1n-\sin\left(\frac1n\right)}{\frac1{n^3}}=\frac16$ very trivial ? Am i missing something very trivial?

Comment: Since$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\cdots,$$you have$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)-x}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\cdots}{x^3}=-\frac16.$$